# How to set several res.locals retrieved from different collections of db? (Express, Mongo, EJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I was trying to clean up my app.js code and fit all res.locals retrieved from db in one app.use method. The moment I did that my app crashed with error that one of res.locals was undefined, which prevented rendering of an ejs view (navbar) nested in another view (header).

Everything works fine if I set my global variables like this

```
//app.js

var express          = require("express"),
    app              = express(),
    ...
    ...

// DB models import
var TranslationService = require("./models/translationservice"),
    Language = require("./models/language"),
    User    = require("./models/user");

// ROUTES import (+ use at the bottom!)
var indexRoutes = require("./routes/index.js"),
    translationServiceRoutes = require("./routes/translationservice.js"),
    languageRoutes = require("./routes/language.js")

// APP config
...
// USER PASSPORT config
...

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');   
    next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    TranslationService.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.translationServiceData = foundItem;
            next();
        }   
    });
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    Language.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.languageData = foundItem;
            next();
        }   
    });
});

// ROUTES use
app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/languages", languageRoutes);
app.use("/translation-services", translationServiceRoutes);

server.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log("server has started");
});
```

I wanted to make my code a bit more dry and unite all res.locals into one app.use method. Like so:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');  

    TranslationService.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.translationServiceData = foundItem;
        }   
    });

    Language.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.languageData = foundItem;
        }   
    });

    next();
});
```

As soon as I do that I get an error. However, If I reload the page multiple times the view is sometimes rendered. I guess in case of an error the view is rendered prior to res.locals retrieval from db.

```
ReferenceError: /Users/.../views/contact.ejs:5
    3| 
    4| <% include partials/head %>
 >> 5| <% include partials/header %>
    6| 
    7| <!-- Page Title
    8| ============================================= -->

/Users/.../views/partials/header.ejs:21
    19|             ============================================= -->
    20| 
 >> 21|             <% include ../partials/navbar %>
    22| 
    23|             <!-- #primary-menu end -->
    24|         </div>

/Users/.../views/partials/navbar.ejs:5
    3|         <li><a href="/translation-services"><div class="on-click">Translation</div></a>
    4|             <ul>
 >> 5|                 <% translationServiceData.sort((a, b) => a.slug.localeCompare(b.slug)); %>
    6|                 <% translationServiceData.forEach(function(item){ %>
    7|                 <li><a href="/translation-services/<%= item.slug %>"><div class="on-click"><%= item.slug %> translation</div></a></li>
    8|                 <% }); %>

translationServiceData is not defined
```

I assume this has to do with node js async loading, but I am not sure and I don't know how to fix this. Or maybe such use of res.locals to build a navbar is an overkill and has to be done another way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: using `mongoose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are calling next() before you get any data from db.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');  

    TranslationService.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.translationServiceData = foundItem;
        }   
    });

    Language.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.languageData = foundItem;
        }   
    });

    //res.locals.translationServiceData and res.locals.languageData
    //are still undefined because the above db calls haven't returned any data yet
    //since the db calls are asynchronous
    next();
});
```

The simplest solution is this

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');  

    TranslationService.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
        if (err || !foundItem) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.locals.translationServiceData = foundItem;
        } 

        Language.find({}, function(err, foundItem) {
            if (err || !foundItem) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.locals.languageData = foundItem;
            }  

            // call next once you have all the data
            next(); 
        });  
    }); 
});
```